# Count distinct occurrences and copy unique values

Tags: excel, google-sheets, libreoffice, openoffice-calc, libreoffice-calc

I am seriously new to MS Excel. What I'm trying to accomplish is:

```
Dates           Distinct dates       # of occurrences
13/Feb/2014     13/Feb/2014          8
13/Feb/2014     14/Feb/2014          5
13/Feb/2014
13/Feb/2014
13/Feb/2014
13/Feb/2014
13/Feb/2014
13/Feb/2014
14/Feb/2014
14/Feb/2014
14/Feb/2014
14/Feb/2014
14/Feb/2014
```

So I have the dates column but want to generate the distinct dates (unique dates) and the number of occurrences that date is listed.

Currently using MS Excel 2003 and/or Google Sheets and/or LibreOffice.

The end product is to generate a line graph.

Comment: A Pivot Table is the easiest way to do this.  Just add one and add the `Date` with a `Count`.  Next step up is copying the column, using `Data->Remove Duplicates` and then `COUNTIF` to count.  Next step up after that is getting the unique list of values via formula and then `COUNTIF`.  If you just want the number, use a Pivot Table; it's dead simple.

Answer (score 2):

Both softwares can easily do that with a `pivot table`.

In Excel: Go to a new tab, select A1 and do `insert, pivot table`.

In google:

Menu: Data, pivot table.

Select your own dates table as interval.
As the rows, or first column, you add your `dates` field.
As the values or the body of the pivot table, add the `dates` again and    select the "countA".

Comment: Yes!! This worked splendid! Thank you. Pivot table was the way to go and so easy. Just to add, I had to first do a: =Datevalue() on the dates first so they sort correctly. Thanks again everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Google Sheets can also produce this output using a formula (assuming your Dates are listed in column A):

`=QUERY({A2:A,A2:A},"select Col1,count(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label Col1'Distinct Dates',count(Col2)'# of occurrences'")`

Answer (score 0):

Using Libreoffice is very easy.

Select Dates column, go to Data - Filter - Standard Filter

Then, condition field pick "**<>**", click en "**more options**" y Select "Without duplicates" and you will have Distinct dates.

You can find  # of occurrences, using "=COUNT.IF(A2:A14;B2)" and change B2 by C2 for the next distinct date